# How can I send api request when popup close in Chrome Extension

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am new in Chrome Extension and I search and read a lot about that.

I have button in popup.html for api request. I clicked that button and api request working as I intented.

But when I close the popup. My requests are stop! I search a lot for that. I saw need is background.js

But I don't know how to configure in my app.

I want to simple app.

1.I want to send api request when even popup close.
2.I want to catch response of requests.
3.I want to add my response message to popup html.

popup.js

```
$(function () {  $("#like").click(function () {
for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    getUrl();
}  }); }); function getUrl() {  setTimeout(() => {
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: 'https://www.instagram.com/explore/tags/visitswitzerland/?__a=1',
  success: function (data) {
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage(null, { "message": data });
  }
});  }, 3000);}
```

background.js

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(  function(request, sender, sendResponse) {
console.log("background : ",request);
if( request.message === "open_max_url" ) {
  fullURL = "http://" + request.url;
  chrome.tabs.create({"url": fullURL, "active": true});
}  });
```

That code runs only when popup open.

What is the correct way for that problem.

Thanks.

Comment: The popup runs only when shown. Use a [background script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages) + [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging).

Comment: I updated my code. But code runs only when popup open. I check it on background console.

Comment: The popup should only send a message. The background script will do $.ajax.

Comment: Thanks. I did solution but I didn't finish. I will publish when i did.